vb.net Email with Godaddy (plesk/windows) hosting
I'm have a "Contact Us" form that I can't get to work on the server.  On localhost it works as intended but I can't get it configured on Godaddy server.  Initially, I was using a NuGet package called EASendmail which works on localhost but not the server. Then I found this in the Godaddy docs and while it's specific to c#, I was able to get it to work on localhost... but not the server.  The only thing I can think of is that I might not have this code in the correct area of web.config.  Otherwise, it's a firewall issue?  If so, any ideas on how I can configure that?
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="your email address">
      <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>

Here's the sub:
 Imports System.Net.Mail

 Public Sub testMail()
     Try
         Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
         Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
         Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
         Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("MyEmail@gmail.com", "MyPassword")
         Smtp_Server.Port = 25
         Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
         Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"



         e_mail = New MailMessage()
         e_mail.From = New MailAddress("MyEmail@gmail.com.com")
         e_mail.To.Add("MyEmail@gmail.com")
         e_mail.Subject = "Test system.net.mail method"
         e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
         e_mail.Body = "That worked from server!"
         Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
         'MsgBox("Mail Sent")

     Catch error_t As Exception
         'MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
     End Try

 End Sub

Here's the web.config entry (I put it between between '<connectionStrings>' and '<system.web>' because I'm not sure where it's supposed to go):
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.net>
   <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="MyEmail@gmail.com">
       <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" />
     </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
 <system.web>

I used port 25 because that's what was in the Godaddy example, and also tried 587. Both work on localhost but not server. I haven't tested with 465.
Any ideas?

Plesae kindly be advised this is something you need to check it with your current provider and ask them about the settings that you need to use.
